# My computer randomly powers off and restarts

Tags: hard-drive, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, reboot

My computer

- Intel i5 7th gen
- 8GB ddr4 (6 months old)
- 2TB hdd Barracuda Seagate
- Gigabyte LGA 1151 motherboard

is 4 years old (used 3 years) and in the middle of some work or even when the system is idle it restarts, the shutdown is not proper and it powers off and restarts. It's the same for windows and any linux. If I turn off my computer and come back after a few hours it'll work fine for sometimes then restarts again, the restarts become more and more frequent for eg I once leaved the system for 10 days it worked fine for about 14 hrs then first restart and the 2nd restart just an hour later

I do not do anything heavy in it just use it for browsing, programming, books etc. I've also checked the temperature and they mostly stay around 40°C

The PSU is some Cooler Master 450 watts, I used to have a graphic card but it went bad last year so it does not have a GPU.

I once started a compilation which involved both CPU and HDD usage and left the room for 20 min came back to see whole system frozen and the same day few hours later I encountered the first restart few days later another restart and they became more and more common.

I've ran a memtest86+ for about 30 mins and it passed 2 tests with 0 errors

I've monitored my cpu usage as well and it's usually 40-60% when I'm using all the apps I use.

I also tried changing the power cord of the system but no help.

As for display I use VGA

Oh and also some of my usb ports and speakers don't work anymore as if there just isn't enough current in the ports.

Could this be a dying motherboard or CPU or HDD?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I might add a bad power supply to the list of suspects (motherboard, cpu), which would probably be the easiest to test/replace. Personal experience, but I can't recall a failing hard drive ever causing reboots for me.

Comment: Run a Prime95 CPU soak test

Comment: "Could this be a dying motherboard or CPU or HDD?" - No; It's likely the PSU.  The fact you had a GPU go out on you points to the PSU.